# Tensorflow - conversion from frozen .pb to .tflite

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to convert a custom frozen .pb file (saved_model.pb & saved_model.pbtxt) to .tflite format so I can load it onto a Coral Dev Board. Trying to convert with the following python code from the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api) (Exporting a quantized GraphDef). The model used was MobileNetV2.

File name: convert.py

```
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.placeholder(name="normalized_input_image_tensor", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 300, 300, 3))
const = tf.constant([1., 2., 3.]) + tf.constant([1., 4., 4.])
val = img + const
out = tf.fake_quant_with_min_max_args(val, min=0., max=1., name="TFLite_Detection_PostProcess")

with tf.Session() as sess:
  converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, [img], [out])
  converter.inference_type = tf.lite.constants.QUANTIZED_UINT8
  input_arrays = converter.get_input_arrays()
  converter.quantized_input_stats = {input_arrays[0] : (0., 1.)}  # mean, std_dev
  tflite_model = converter.convert()
  open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Being new and naive to tensorflow, I *think* my input and outputs are as follows

**Input**
[image: Input]

**Output**
[image: Output]

After running the python code above, the converted .tflite model that outputs is only 1kb in size and looks too simplistic. 
[image: tflite output]

There are several questions really in this.

1. Is the input in the python code correct? Particularly, name="normalized_input_image_tensor"
2. Is the output in the python code correct? Particularly, name="TFLite_Detection_PostProcess"
3. What shape should the .tflite output take - should it be more complex?

Thanks! Appreciate your patience with newbs as I stumble through.

Visualizations with - https://github.com/lutzroeder/Netron

EDIT, found this which gave me the input name

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> gf = tf.GraphDef()
>>> gf.ParseFromString(open('saved_model.pb','rb').read())
>>> [n.name + '=>' +  n.op for n in gf.node if n.op in ( 'Softmax','Placeholder')]
```

OUTPUT: ['normalized_input_impage_tesnor=>Placeholder']

changed code to

```
img = tf.placeholder(name="Placeholder", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 300, 300, 3))
const = tf.constant([1., 2., 3.]) + tf.constant([1., 4., 4.])
val = img + const
out = tf.fake_quant_with_min_max_args(val, min=0., max=1., name="MobilenetV2/Predictions/Softmax")
```

with same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tflite_convert --output_file=converted_model.tflite --graph_def_file=saved_model.pb --input_arrays=input --output_arrays=TFLite_Detection_PostProcess,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3  --input_shape=1,300,300,3 --allow_custom_ops
```

And now it works.